# Mule 3.6 Rest component not working and getting resource not found issue

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

Here is the mule configuration and class code respectively .Problem is HTTP listener is not listening at the path http://localhost:9091/test

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="9091" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="restFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component class="com.syn.rest.test" />
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>


@Path("test") 
public class test {         

@GET    
public String method() 
{
    return "It works";  
}
}
```

Note: Same code is working with Mule 3.5 EE but not with Mule 3.6.1 EE and 3.7 EE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, with star * on path.

```
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

Comment: why @Context HttpServletRequest returns null always?

Comment: not entirely sure. do you inject that in class or in method?

Comment: I tried in class as well as method and i got null in both cases.I tried with servlet connector insted of http connector then also sam prbolem it's returning null always

Comment: Hmm could be a limitation. See this thread before, http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/4903/problem_building_a_rest_api_with_context_annotation.html Unsure if it worked with Jetty, it ended there.